# CSS class wont apply on html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble attaching CSS class to HTML div. I've tried many ways but none of them work.

Weird thing is that the buttons in div with id="buttons" moved to center with CSS styling but the div with id="questions" inside it didn't. How can I get the questions div placed in the middle with buttons?

[PICTURE OF HOW IT LOOKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJOPY.png)

**HTML**

```
<body>
<script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
            appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.8'
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });   
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function statusChangeCallback(response){
        if(response.status === 'connected'){
            console.log('Logged in and authenticated');
            setElements(true);
        } else {
            console.log('Not authenticated');
            setElements(false);
        }
    }

    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }

    function setElements(isLoggedIn) {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            document.getElementById('logout').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('profile').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('fb-btn').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('heading').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('buttons').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('logout').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('profile').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('fb-btn').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('heading').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('buttons').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    function logout() {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
            setElements(false);
        });
    }
</script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Relvaeksam</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a id="logout" href="#" onclick="logout()">Logi välja</a></li>
            <fb:login-button
            id="fb-btn"
            scope="public_profile,email,user_birthday,user_location,user_posts"
            onlogin="checkLoginState();">
            </fb:login-button>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <h3 id="heading">Logige sisse, et alustada testimist</h3>
    <div id="profile">

    </div>
</div>

<div id="buttons">
    <button class="button starter" style="background-color: #4CAF50;" onClick="startQuiz()">Alusta testimist</button>
    <div id="questions"></div>
    <button class="button ender" type="button" onclick="checkAnswers()">Valmis</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>
</body>`
```

**CSS**

```
#buttons {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.button {
    background-color: #F6F4F4;
}

.button.ender {
    color: black;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
        border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button.starter {
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
        color: black; 
        border: 2px solid #008CBA;
}
```

Comment: try adding `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` in #questions

Comment: Your questions div is inside the buttons div with the same css styles being applied in different ways.  Best way to see what is being applied is to right click your browser page, go to inspect, and look at the styles tab.  If there is a styling you always want to take priority you can use !important in your css

Comment: thank you for replying so fast :) I updated the code a little, `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto`  doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I looked into your jsfiddle and saw that your div with the "questions" id is empty. Then I added something inside it to see if was centering or not, and when i added, it really wasn't centered.

This is why: first, you applied a left margin in the "buttons" div:

```
#buttons {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

and then, you applied another margin in "questions":

```
#questions {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

In CSS, a div inside another div inherits its "father" behavior, so, the "questions" div didn't need another left margin since its father, the "buttons" div already had it.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juu7jsna/6/) with a fixed version.

You can see that in the CSS I removed the margin-left from the child div, the "questions" div.

Hope my answer covers all your problems.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I forgot to mention, that a table is appended to "questions" div with javascript. here is how it looks: [link](https://gyazo.com/392150946d7907b9aa504b0a940612a1)   @Julio